# Android cPanel app

Tags: vps

Are there Android status apps available for cPanel?

Any other suggestions for mobile quick views of the server status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check,

1. [Control Panel for cPanel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cpanel.remote&hl=en)
2. [Crazy Remote Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scienpix.crazyremotelite&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnNjaWVucGl4LmNyYXp5cmVtb3RlbGl0ZSJd)

Answer (score 1):

This came up on a google search:

https://market.android.com/details?id=net.cpanel.remote&hl=en

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I've been waiting for, now - for the WHM version ;)